# CSS doesn't link anymore to specific folders

Tags: html, css, angularjs, relative-path

Using angular-fullstack generator to scaffold my app I woke up with the CSS not linking anymore to 2 specific folders. Checking Chrome console showed me that one of my css files wasn't indeed linked correctly but I haven't been able to correct the problem by myself.

EDIT: it seems that my problem comes from index.html as I was able to get part of my css. Here it is :

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<base href="/">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!-- build:css(client) app/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

  <!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css({.tmp,client}) app/app.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/app.css">
  <!-- injector:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/account/account.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/admin/admin.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/main/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/superhero/css/compiled/layout.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/superhero/css/compiled/elements.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/superhero/css/libs/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/work/work.css">
  <!-- endinjector -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I don't understand why it works now because main/main.html was using layout.css correctly despite not calling the file either. Anyway, fonts are not linked while I am pretty sure to call them right.

/// End of edit

[image: every html file from account and admin folders are unstyled except what is declared in account.css. If I copy the missing CSS in this file, everything is back to normal.]

every html file from account and admin folders are unstyled except what is declared in account.css. If I copy the missing CSS in this file, everything is back to normal.

The weirdest fact for me is that any account/*.html file calls components/navbar/navbar.html which won't be printed correctly either, while it works fine in any other include.

The specificity of these folders is that they have account.js and admin.js, which contain their own stateprovider.

```
angular.module('yoyo')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'app/account/login/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
  .state('signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    templateUrl: 'app/account/signup/signup.html',
    controller: 'SignupCtrl'
  })
  ....
```

Anyway, if I put the code in work.js, which contains every other state, it doesn't work either. Nor taking every piece of code to app folder.

Finally, I get a lot of trouble understanding the generator, as it won't let me link some of my CSS into the index.html file. Or it tries to rewrite the paths I provide. All I know is that is was working yesterday without me pushing any relevant code I believe, and that the main folder contains exactly the same css as any html file in the account folder.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the relative path, try to use absolute using slash at the beginning.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/app.css">
                             ^^
etc.
```